# Automatically start a progress bar without a button click in java

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

I have here a sample of  progress bar:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Container;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;

    public class ProgressSample {
      public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("JProgressBar Sample");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container content = f.getContentPane();
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setValue(25);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Reading...");
        progressBar.setBorder(border);
        content.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.setSize(300, 100);
        f.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Now.. Is there a way to make the value run from 0 - 100% without a button triggering it. Like when I run that frame the `Thread` or `Timer` will automatically start. Is there a way to make it? Or I still need a button to trigger the timer/thread?

Comment: Simple answer is ... yes ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer How can I do that? Can you teach me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about seeking a tutor.

Comment: @AndrewThompson oh. Is that not allowed? Well not that I'm seeking a tutor. I just want to know how to do that.

Comment: *"Can you teach me?"*  What is 'you' in that statement if *not* a tutor?

Comment: @AndrewThompson someone who can show me an example :)

Comment: To dispel the impression that you are investing 0 effort in helping yourself, include an MCVE of *"a way to make the value run from 0 - 100% **with** a button triggering it"*.  From that, it is a trivial edit for an helper to make it do it automatically.

Comment: *"someone who can show me an example"*  That's more 'spoon feeding' than 'teaching/instructing'.  ..And SO is **not a code factory.**

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay. I'm sorry for that. but I did post a sample.

Comment: I second that, you should have done a simple search to find an answer online first, you would have found numerous simple examples straight away.

Comment: @eitanfar i did but I only found the ones with button triggering the start of the timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer is, yes.

You can update the progress bar at any time, so long as you do it from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  What you will require is some way to tell the `JProgressBar` what it's new value should be, but that will depend on what it is you are trying to achieve.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class AutoProgress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AutoProgress();
    }

    private JProgressBar pb;
    private int progress;

    public AutoProgress() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                pb = new JProgressBar();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(pb);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        progress += 1;
                        if (progress >= 100) {
                            progress = 100;
                            ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                        }
                        pb.setValue(progress);
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You might also like to have a look at [`JProgressBar#setIndeterminate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate(boolean)).

You should also have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look at the links you've provided.